# C# Setting Entity Framework connectionstring in controller

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4, repository-pattern, asp.net-web-api, unit-of-work

I'm build my webapi project based on this article: [A simple POC using ASP.NET Web API, Entity Framework, Autofac, Cross Domain Support](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/350488/A-simple-POC-using-ASP-NET-Web-API-Entity-Framewor)

However, I need to pass a connection string to the `DbContext` because a user that connects to the webapi can select a different database to work with.

Where and what is that best way to implement this? In the controller, having a separate 'service' or a singleton?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm currently building a website that requires multiple databases also.  This is the basics (for now).  It may not be the best/efficient way, but it does the job so that I can continue working on the site.

Let's say you have this connection and everything there is correct, except the database name can change.

```
<add name="MyDbContext" connectionString="Server=SomeConnection;Database=SomeDatabase;"providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

You can create a connection string on the fly with this

```
public MyDbContext CreateDbContext(string databaseName)
{
    SqlConnectionStringBuilder sqlBuilder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyDbContext"].ConnectionString);  // Gets the default connection
    sqlBuilder.InitialCatalog = databaseName;  // Update the database name

    return new MyDbContext(sqlBuilder.ToString());
}
```

Also, unless you want to automatically create a database if it doesn't exist, possibly from incorrect database name, you need to set the initializer.  Simply pass the initializer null to prevent ef from automatically creating one.  I set this in the constructor of MyDbContext

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    /* some other constructors */

    public MyDbContext(string nameOrConnectionString, bool createDb)
        : base(nameOrConnectionString)
    {
        if(!createdDb)
        {
            System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer<MyDbContext>(null);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to have multiple ConnectionStrings in your web config. You could then select which ConnectionString to use depending on a parameter passed to your webapi:

In your web config:

```
  <connectionStrings>
<add name="dataBase1" connectionString="/*db info here*/" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

<add name="dataBase2" connectionString="/*db info here*/" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Then in your code:

```
public someobject GetData(/*arguments*/, string dbType)
{
    var connectionString = dbType == 'dataBase1'  
    ? ConfigurationManager.ConnectionString['dataBase1'].toString() 
    : ConfigurationManager.ConnectionString['dataBase2'].toString()

    /*then pass connectionString to dbContext*/
    var dbContext = new DbContext(connectionString);
}
```

Comment: I have my connectionstrings in a separate db. I was thinking of using a cookie with the request. However, I still do not know how to set the connectionstring in DatabaseFactory class.